# How to increment varchar value like AEC00001

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

i have to increment a string value  by 1, like default value will be  AEC00001 and second value will be AEC00002 and so on, how can i achieve this by using c# or sql query.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: You have to extract the integer part, increment, and convert back. But why are you having this problem? Aren't you trying to solve a problem that shouldn't be there?

Comment: if i am extracting integer part and adding 1 on it (00001+1= 2) but i need 00002

Comment: What is the main reason for doing this? This might help give some more context and what the actual problem is. If you have only 10 entries for example that would most likely give a different answer than if you said it was unknown and you had to loop through a collection.

Comment: You see, maybe you're having this problem because of a bad design somewhere?

Comment: AEC00001 this is my id in one of my table , and i have to increment that id by 1.

Comment: What is this for? Is it for a table in sql? Is it for a datatable in a c# app or something similar? Give more context so people can help.

Comment: Is this a HEX number saved as text? Which number comes after `AEC99999`?

Comment: Please provide some code, that we can enhance. We can't write the programm for you. But tipp. Split your id in two parts. Prefix = String = "AEC" and Index = Integer = "0001". Then you can Index++ and concanate Prefix + Index to get your ID.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bad design somewhere in your application. Probably you should store number and prefix separately.

But anyway, assuming your prefix is always "AEC" and size of number is five decimal places - you can increment your values like (this is c# solution since you haven't specified if you prefer sql solution to c# one):

```
string s = "AEC00001";
string s1 = "AEC" + 
    (Convert.ToInt32(s.Replace("AEC", "")) + 1)
        .ToString()
        .PadLeft(5, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant store 0000 before number in INT format, but you can do something like that:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000' + CAST(2 AS varchar(5)) , 5)
```

OR

```
SELECT '0000' + CAST(2 AS varchar(5))
```

Comment: But in case of AEC0009 this query will return value like this AEC0091 which is wrong. i need AEC0010

Answer (score 0):

Here I used computed column which automatically takes other column and con-cats to it

```
declare @a table ( a as 'AEC'+b, b nvarchar(max))

insert into @a  SELECT RIGHT('00000'+CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(5)),5)union select RIGHT('00000'+CAST(2 AS VARCHAR(5)),5) union select RIGHT('00000'+CAST(3 AS VARCHAR(5)),5)

select * from @a
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var originalValue = "AEC00002";
// Get the numeric part (00002)
var stringValue = Regex.Match(originalValue, @"\d+").Value;
// Convert to int
var intValue = Int32.Parse(stringValue);
// Increase
intValue++;
// Convert back to string
originalValue = "AEC" + intValue.ToString("D5");
```

Result: AEC00003

Answer (score 0):

You may use a computed column:

> A computed column is a column that expresses the data that can be used by an other column in the same table. This expression can be non-computed columns or any function and constant. It cannot be a sub-query. Here the computed column is marked as Persisted, so that any update made in the referenced column will be automatically synchronized in the computed column.

For more information, see this article: [Auto Incremented Column With VARCHAR and NVARCHAR Data Type in SQL](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/auto-incremented-column-with-varchar-and-nvarchar-data-type/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21782493)

Answer (score 0):

**In JavaScript Use the below function**

```js
function autoIncrementCustomId(lastRecordId){
  let increasedNum = Number(lastRecordId.replace('ABC','')) + 1;
  let kmsStr = lastRecordId.substr(0,3);
  for(let i=0; i< 6 - increasedNum.toString().length; i++){
    kmsStr = kmsStr+'0';
  }
  kmsStr = kmsStr + increasedNum.toString();
  console.log(kmsStr);
}

autoIncrementCustomId('ABC009999')
```